# Mac OS X: How to permanently change the prompt (value of PS1) in the shell of emacs client?

Tags: macos, emacsclient

I have start emacs as daemon through (`emacs --daemon`). I then launch the client (`emacsclient -c`) and use its shell mode through (`M-x shell RET`). However the prompt starts with:

> bash-3.2$

I have changed the value of `PS1` by `export PS1="\w\$ "` in `.bash_profile`. So any idea how to change the value of `PS1` in the shell of emacsclient?

**Edit:** or an equal question is: where does emacsclient get environment variables, e.g. $PATH, $PS1 ...? Knowing this will solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

.bash_profile won't be executed.  Put the PS1 inside .bashrc